# How to make column value a new row in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that I would like to reformat by making the first column its own row above the values.

I want this:

```
| Type | Value1 | Value2 |
| -----| ------ | ------ |
| A    | 1      | 3      |
| B    | 2      | 2      |
```

To become this with the rows containing "A" and "B" to be merged cells:

```
|      | Value1 | Value2 |
| -----| ------ | ------ |
| A                      |
|      | 1      | 3      |
| B                      |
|      | 2      | 2      |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `insertRows` function from `berryFunctions` package:
For your original data you may adapt c(1,3) -> for example with a sequence:

```
library (berryFunctions)
librar(dplyr)

insertRows(df, c(1,3), new="") %>% 
  mutate(Type = lead(Type, default = ""))
```

```
  Type Value1 Value2
1    A              
2           1      3
3    B              
4           2      2
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you merge the cells in the new rows (1 and 3) so that it's a single cell?

Comment: Would you be so kind to make a reproducible example and open a new question. I am sorry but I do not understand the new task. Many thanks.